# How to add limit to display selected items in drop-down box and rest selected item as hidden to display counter numbers autocomplete material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, multi-select, chips

How to display material Ui autocomplete multiselect selected items as only 2 options in drop-down and if user selects more then 2 items then it should display 1+ item selected. If user select 4 items then it should display 2+ items and so on when I Focus or click in drop downs field then  all selected items should be display.

How to do custom functionalalty in ReactJS material ui drop-down autocomplete multiselect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.